# Python SMTP what is wrong with the syntax?

Tags: python, smtp

I am very new to this whole Python 3.4 syntax and need some help working out this portion of my SMTP mailer. Anyways, if you could help that would be great! Below is the code in Python script.

```
    print ('SMTP Mailbox Spammer v1')

import smtplib

smtpObj = smptlib.SMTP( [smtp.gmail.com [ 465]] )


receive = str(input('Receiver: '))
subject = str(input('Subject: '))
message = str(input('Message: '))

   sender = 'johnappleseed3113@gmail.com'
   receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

   message = """From: From Person <johnappleseed3113@gmailc.om>
   To: To Person <"""receive""">
   Subject: """subject"""

   """message"""
   """

   try:
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
      smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
      print "Successfully sent email"
   except SMTPException:
      print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like you're making a spam bot, which is unethical.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove tab below.

sender = 'johnappleseed3113@gmail.com'
   receivers = ['to@todomain.com']

message = """From: From Person 
   To: To Person <"""receive""">
   Subject: """subject"""

"""message"""
   """

try:
      smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
      smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
      print "Successfully sent email"
   except SMTPException:
      print "Error: unable to send email"

Comment: It's somewhat working... I'm modifying it so that it does work. One thing I found was that sender and receivers both have to be on separate lines.